# TextBlock issue when long text and TextTrimming

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a TextBlock with `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"`, `TextWrapping="NoWrap"` and very long text about 140 000 symbols. I put this text into the TextBlock, and then the TextBlock shows this text as multiline control whith trimming in an each row.

### XAML

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="500"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

### C#

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
            public MainWindow() {
                InitializeComponent();
                string str = "q ";
                for(int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
                    str += "qwetre ";
                }
                textBlock.Text = str;
            }
        }
```

[image]

Any ideas? Is it bug of MS, or I can change this behaviour?

Comment: bug? maybe somebody likes it that way.

Comment: looks documented to me http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming.aspx

Comment: how do you want the textblock behave?

Comment: I ran this project exactly as you have shown and I only see one row!

Comment: @Jodrell the documented link which you have provided only displays the results over multiple lines because of the explicit <linebreak> tags in the textbox text

Comment: @Danield thanks, I found that it is with 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 2):

The Textblock `TextWrapping` property is by default set to NoWrap.

Therefore, unless you

1. explicitly set it to Wrap/WrapWithOverflow  or
2. add `<LineBreak/>` tags with the text

the text will always be displayed over one line only.

@Mirimon I ran this project exactly as you have shown and I only see one row!

Answer (score 2):

I have found answer on my question. The TextBlock has this behaviour with 4.5 framework (I had install VS2012), I tried in on computer without VS2012, work correctly, only one row.